# Why RealityKit ARView marked as @objc?

Tags: swift, realitykit

Apple said that RealityKit SDK was written from scratch for Swift only. There's no Obj-C.

```
@objc class ARView
```

But why its ARView has a keyword "@objc"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why its ARView has a keyword "@objc"?

For the very reason you gave. It is written entirely in Swift, and an ARView is not a UIView subclass. Therefore, Objective-C code can't see this class at all without the `@objc` keyword.

After all, you still might have a project partly or entirely written in Objective-C that would still need to talk to this class. Objective-C programmers do still exist!

To put it another way, this class may not be *written* in Objective-C, but we don't want to keep it *secret* from Objective-C.

Comment: I think Apple may eventually intend for RealityKit to utilized by objective-c code.  However, as of Xcode 12.3 and iOS 14.3, Swift frameworks (e.g. RealityKit) cannot be utilized with objective c code.

Comment: The statement "ARView is not a UIView subclass" seems incorrect. Checkout ARViews Xcode documentation: ARView -> typealias: ARViewBase -> UIView (most likely NSView on macOS - OSX)